# How to build a project in debug rather that release in msvc command line

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, linker, visual-studio-debugging, cl

I have makefile and multiple *.mak files for a cpp project which gives release build.
I want to have a debug build so that I can debug some crt functions.
For compiling cl is used 
linker is link 
The flags are overwhelming for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to build a project in debug rather that release in msvc command line

You can try to build the project in MSBuild command line with argument `/property:Configuration=Debug`, like:

```
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe YourProject.proj /target:rebuild "/property:Configuration=Debug
```

[image]

Check the document [MSBuild command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2017) for some more details.

Hope this helps.